# Better/correct approach to solve arithmetic modulo problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Suppose that a and b are integers, a ≡ 4 (mod 13) and b ≡ 9 (mod 13). Find the integer c with 0 ≤ c ≤ 12 such that

a) c ≡ 9a (mod 13)

I'm trying to solve the first part, few approaches I've tried,

[First Approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao6rG.jpg)

[Second Approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX9KD.jpg)

Comment: Where does  $b$ come in here?

Comment: 'b' is used in other parts of the question. The question is from Discrete Mathematics - K Rosen

Comment: Thank you. Is it legal to replace ≡ with = sign? How you replace c≡9a(mod13) with  c=9a(mod13)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second approach is dodgier than the first: you assume $0 \leq a \leq 12$ and then show that $a=4$, which is correct but not really relevant.

Your first approach is correct.

If you want to be more formal about it, you could say $a = 13n + 4$, so $$c = 9(13n+4) = 9 \times 13n + 9 \times 4 = 9 \times 13n + (2 \times 13 + 10) = (9n + 2) \times 13 + 10$$
which is $10$ mod $13$. But the reasoning in your first approach is fine.

Comment: Great I will go with first approach and also thank you for giving the formal approach.

Comment: Thank you. Is it legal to replace $\equiv$ with $=$ sign? How you replace $c \equiv 9a \pmod {13}$ with $c = 9a \pmod {13}$

Comment: @Avra I have used the $=$ sign only to make statements about equality of integers, not about equivalence mod $13$.

Comment: Thank you again. In the discrete math book, they did not mention this concept, so pardon me if I did not fully get the point. Is it possible to put what you said in other simpler words?

Comment: The statement $c = 9(13n+4) = 9 \times 13n + 9 \times 4 = 9 \times 13n + (2 \times 13 + 10) = (9n + 2) \times 13 + 10$ is not a statement about modular arithmetic. It's a statement about integers. So $=$ is the correct symbol to use.